# graphql err: object not extensible. Way to change object and replace in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, graphql

I have a graphql query called albums. In my album object, there are images, so `albums:[{album1..., images:[array_of_IDs]}, {album2..., images:[array_of_IDs]}]`. I would like to add 1 ID to images in a specific album.

I tried this, but I get "Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible" in chrome.

```
const currentAlbum = data.albums.find(album => album.id === this.state.albumId)
const currentAlbumImages = currentAlbum.images
currentAlbumImages.push(newImage.id)//the ID is typeof String
```

I AM able to push or delete an album from `albums`.

**Answering 1 of these will solve my problem:**

1. Is there a JS way to get the album object, copy it, push a new ID to images array in it, then `splice()` the old album object out of `albums` array and push the new one with the image ID in?
2. Is there a reason why this graphql push to part of an object isn't working? How can I fix it?

Comment: The second statement should be `currentAlbumImages.images.push(id)`, this statement will add a new id to your `images` array in the found object.

Comment: in my const = .... it has .images. I will update to reflect this.